# Will enabling binding security help prevent against DOS attacks?

Tags: .net, wcf, security

I have a service based on NetTcpBinding. The service is configured to handle large volumes of data:

```
.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2000000
.MaxBufferPoolSize = 2000000
.MaxBufferSize = 2000000
.MaxArrayLength = 2000000
.MaxBytesPerRead = 2000000
```

and therefore might be vulnerable to DOS attacks.

Will the use of security (`SecurityMode.Message` in particular), reduce the effects of a possible DOS attack (specifically, an attack designed to flood the system with very large messages)?

Answer (score 0):

The Message transfer security mode simply encrypts the message itself. By encrypting the message, you gain integrity and privacy and enable mutual authentication, for the same reason that Transport security provides these features when the communication channel is encrypted. However, encrypting the message rather than the transport enables the service to communicate securely over nonsecure transports, such as HTTP. Because of that, Message security provides for end-to-end security, regardless of the number of intermediaries involved in transferring the message and regardless of whether or not the transport is secure. In addition, Message security is based on a set of industry standards designed both for interoperability and for thwarting common attacks such as replay and DOS attacks.